# sending multiple sensor data on kaa server using C SDK

Tags: kaa

I need to read multiple sensor data from one single  bradboard which is connected to a raspberry pi. We are getting one sensor's data properly, but when we are connecting multiple sensors, we are  not sure how to read data from multiple sensors. I am using C SDK of KAA server.  i have used the demo_client file to write in log record and dh11.c file to find temreture value.  thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the code to do separate readings of the sensors samples and upload them to Kaa server as a set of records (this would be the simplest to start with).

Then, you will most probably need to modify the log schema to be able differentiating the telemetry date between sensors.